# How to switch to wayland after upgrade to 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, wayland

Just migrated from *Ubuntu-Gnome 16.10* to *17.04* to *Ubuntu 17.10* (mistake by me, I know the step was not necessary).

Now I have clearly the new GNOME Desktop with its ubuntu-modifications, but It is everything running on `X11`, according to `echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE` which displays `x11`.

How can I switch to *wayland* now? I have *weston* and *wayland* packages installed. I use the *nouveau* driver on my *thinkpad*, so no proprietary drivers.

Any hints welcome.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  After an upgrade (from an updated but nearly default17.04 ) the login choices offered were 1)Gnome on xorg, 2)Ubuntu on xorg, and 3)unity.  Hardware is i7 quad core, Nvidia Quadro 1000M running the nouveau driver.  What hardware do you have. What choices are offered at the login gear?

Comment: @pomsky that post you linked to has been deleted.  The 404 page even suggests this one to search for more real info.

Comment: @phord "*This question was voluntarily removed by its author.*", so nothing we can do about it! And where exactly does the 404 page suggest "this one to search **for more real info**"? I can't see any! Only thing I can see is a list of questions with the title "Here are some similar questions that **might be relevant**" (emphasis mine).

Comment: @pomsky That question, including the OP's comment, [can be viewed in the Google cache](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:O_R8BuA6268J:https://askubuntu.com/questions/967611/no-wayland-session-only-x+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us). If you need information from it to write an answer or comment, you can view it there, for now. (The Google Cache won't keep it forever... though you could ask a [10k user](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) for the information.)

Comment: Do you have the gear icon on your login screen? Normally you click it to choose between a Xorg and a Wayland session.

Comment: are you sure you have at least `xwayland` installed ? Another possibility could be your graphics card: Is it NVIDIA ? Then [this comment](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gdm3/+bug/1724583/comments/7) on a bug report could be interesting for you.